# Give an example of two rotations that commute in $S^2$.

Tags: geometry

spherical geometry question involving isometries in $S^2$

Give an example of two rotations $R_1$ and $R_2$, of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$ such that $R_1R_2 = R_2R_1$

Also, give an example of two rotations in $S^2$ that do not commute.

Rotation involves rotation of the sphere around an axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: Two rotations of a sphere around the same axis always commute.

Hint 2: Most rotations do *not* commute, so if you just pick two example rotations, chances are they will not commute.

Comment: Do you mean to pick to different axis of rotations?

Comment: I mean to pick rotations around the same axis to find two rotations that do commute, and rotations around different axes to find two that do not commute.

Comment: Alright thanks!