# Examples of isometries of $S^2$

Tags: real-analysis, projective-geometry

Hey guys I am trying to do some practice problems for my course and I came across this problem, like I know what isometries are and how they work. But I am getting confused on how I would apply the same procedure to a sphere and I am confused on that.

1) Find two rotations of the sphere $r$, $r'$ such that $rr' = r'r$.

2) Find two rotations of the sphere $r$, $r'$ such that $rr' \neq r'r$.

3) Find an isometry of $S^2$ with no fixed points.

Please help out, itll be really appreciated thank you

Comment: [This person](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/64609/mathlover) appears to be in the same course as you: [1, 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/321984/856), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/321990/856). You two should hang out.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/321984). This question asks about isometries and includes a question about no fixed points. That question asks about rotations.

Comment: @robjohn: That's the trouble when people ask three questions in one. Parts 1 and 2 ask about *rotations* and are a duplicate of the linked question. Part 3 asks about an isometry with no fixed points, and is a duplicate of link no. 3 in my previous comment. Unfortunately, the software only let me vote to close as a duplicate of *one* existing question.

Comment: @RahulNarain: I was responding to the note added to the question. I see that these questions have been asked (and answered) before. Let's hope these comments keep anyone from voting to reopen.

Comment: sorry about that guys I really had no clue someone already posted it. I really dont know these people

Answer (score 2):

1) Take $r = r'$ ;

2) take $r$ and $r'$ with orthogonal axis ;

3) $x \to - x$.

Comment: For 2) you could, of course, be unlucky and pick rotations with angle $\pi$.